# how to define an Array of objects of a interface? myData:Array<myInterface>=[]; I am getting Property 'xxxxxx' does not exist on type 'myInterface[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to define an interface for an array of objects, where I want the initial value in the component to be an empty array

I have an interface in a file:

```
export interface myInterface{
 "picture": string,
 "lastUpdated": Date
}
```

In my component I import this interface:

```
import {myInterface} from "./interfaces/myInterface"
.
.
myData:Array<myInterface>=[];  //default [] initial value
.
.
//I get the data by a rest api
then((data) => {
  this.myData=data;
  this.myData.lastUpdated= new Date();  //Property 'lastUpdated' does not exist on type 'myInterface[]'
})
```

I am getting this error:

```
this.myData.lastUpdated= new Date();  //Property 'lastUpdated' does not exist on type
```

how can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you want the first value of `lastUpdated` or all of them.
`myData` is an array of objects, you should loop through it in order to handle all its values

```js
myData: MyInterface[] = []; // EMPTY array of type MyInterface
myLastUpdatedArray: any = []; // EMPTY array of type any
...
then((data) => {
  this.myData = data;

  const aVariable = this.myData[0].lastUpdate; // aVariable will hold your .lastUpdated value
 
  // if you want all of them
  myData.forEach((data) => this.myLastUpdatedArray.push(data.lastUpdated));
})
```

Comment: I am having typing (typescript) problems. I don't know how to define myData with type `myInterface` like an array of objects empty

Comment: Look at the code again, the first line, declares an empty array of type `MyInterface`. You should read more about how `Typescript` works.

Comment: `myData: MyInterface[] = []; this.myData.lastUpdated= new Date();`  //Property 'lastUpdated' does not exist  on type `myInterface[]`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are *trying* to accomplish - but the error message is self-explanatory: `myData` is array, not an object.

You *could* do, for example,

```
this.myData.push(data);
this.myData[0].lastUpdated= new Date();
```

or something similar

Comment: I am having typing (typescript) problems. I don't know how to define myData with type `myInterface` like an array of objects empty

Comment: huh? you have `myData: MyInterface[] = []; - why is that the problem?

Comment: myData: MyInterface[] = []; this.myData.lastUpdated= new Date(); //Property 'lastUpdated' does not exist on type myInterface[]

Comment: did you read the answer? actually, two answers tell you the same thing